# Simple pattern matching between two string inputs using Java (Google interview challenge)

Tags: java, strings, interview-questions, reinventing-the-wheel

The interview question is:

> Write a function `isMatch` (without using `java.util.Regex`) that takes two strings as arguments:
>
> - `s` (a string to match), and
> - `p` (a regular expression pattern).
>
> It should return a Boolean denoting whether `s` matches `p`.
>
> `p` can be composed of alphabetic characters and '*' (denoting that the previous character matches 0 or more times).

This is the code I have written:

```
    private boolean isNextCharStarred(String s) {
         return s.length() >= 2 && s.charAt(1) == '*';
     }

     private boolean recIsMatch(String s, String p, boolean hasPatternBeenEaten) {
         if (p.length() == 0) {
             return true;
         }
         if (s.length() == 0) {
             if (isNextCharStarred(p)) {
                 return recIsMatch(s, p.substring(2), true);
             }
             return p.length() == 0;
         }
         if (isNextCharStarred(p)) {
             if (s.charAt(0) != p.charAt(0)) {
                 return recIsMatch(s, p.substring(2), true);
             }
             return recIsMatch(s.substring(1), p, hasPatternBeenEaten) 
|| recIsMatch(s, p.substring(2), true);
         }
         if (s.charAt(0) == p.charAt(0)) {
             return recIsMatch(s.substring(1), p.substring(1), true);
         }
         if (hasPatternBeenEaten) {
             return false;
         }
         return recIsMatch(s.substring(1), p, hasPatternBeenEaten);
     }

     public boolean isMatch(String s, String p) {
         return recIsMatch(s, p, false);
     }
```

Are there any bugs? How could it be improved?

Answer (score 1):

#### Empty pattern should only match empty text

`isMatch("aa", "a")` returns `true`, when it should be `false`.
The problem is with this condition:

> ```
>  if (p.length() == 0) {
>      return true;
>  }
> ```

An empty pattern should match only an empty text:

```
 if (p.isEmpty()) {
     return s.isEmpty();
 }
```

Notice that I replaced `s.length() == 0` with `s.isEmpty()`.
This is a more natural way to check if a string is empty.

#### Use better variable names

Instead of `s` and `p` it would be more natural to call them `text` and `pattern`.

The function `isNextCharStarred` is always used on the pattern,
but its parameter is called `s`, which is the same name as the variable used for text in the other function. Even `p` would have been less confusing. `pattern` would be nice and natural.

#### Eliminate `hasPatternBeenEaten`

The parameter `hasPatternBeenEaten` looked a bit suspicious to me.
Let's take a closer look.

The value of the variable is only read in one place in the code.
Let's look at the piece code just before that:

> ```
>  if (isNextCharStarred(p)) {
>      // will always return from this block
>  }
>  if (s.charAt(0) == p.charAt(0)) {
>      return ...
>  }
>  if (hasPatternBeenEaten) {
>      return false;
>  }
> ```

That is:

- If the pattern starts with `X*` (where `X` is any letter), the first `if` block will return.
- If the pattern doesn't start with `X*`, and the first characters match, the second `if` block will return.
- If the pattern doesn't start with `X*`, and the first characters don't match, then we need not look further: the pattern doesn't match, we can `return false`.

Therefore, the `hasPatternBeenEaten` is unnecessary, and can be safely eliminated.

#### Simplify

With the above changes, the code will look more like this:

```
  private boolean isMatch(String text, String pattern) {
    if (pattern.isEmpty()) {
      return text.isEmpty();
    }

    if (text.isEmpty()) {
      if (isNextCharStarred(pattern)) {
        return isMatch(text, pattern.substring(2));
      }
      return pattern.isEmpty();
    }

    if (isNextCharStarred(pattern)) {
      if (text.charAt(0) != pattern.charAt(0)) {
        return isMatch(text, pattern.substring(2));
      }
      return isMatch(text.substring(1), pattern)
        || isMatch(text, pattern.substring(2));
    }

    if (text.charAt(0) == pattern.charAt(0)) {
      return isMatch(text.substring(1), pattern.substring(1));
    }

    return false;
  }
```

This can probably be written simpler, by rearranging the conditions and extracting common patterns.

First of all the second `pattern.isEmpty()` condition is redundant,
because at that point we already know that `pattern` is not empty,
due to the very first condition in the method.

Next, we can extract the common condition `text.charAt(0) == pattern.charAt(0)` to a variable `firstMatch`, and flatten the `if` conditions to direct `return` statements, like this:

```
if (pattern.isEmpty()) {
  return text.isEmpty();
}

if (text.isEmpty()) {
  return isNextCharStarred(pattern) && isMatch(text, pattern.substring(2));
}

boolean firstMatch = text.charAt(0) == pattern.charAt(0);

if (isNextCharStarred(pattern)) {
  return firstMatch && isMatch(text.substring(1), pattern)
    || isMatch(text, pattern.substring(2));
}

return firstMatch && isMatch(text.substring(1), pattern.substring(1));
```

Lastly, we can generalize `firstMatch` to include the case of empty text,
which will make the second `if` redundant:

```
if (pattern.isEmpty()) {
  return text.isEmpty();
}

boolean firstMatch = !text.isEmpty() && text.charAt(0) == pattern.charAt(0);

if (isNextCharStarred(pattern)) {
  return firstMatch && isMatch(text.substring(1), pattern)
    || isMatch(text, pattern.substring(2));
}

return firstMatch && isMatch(text.substring(1), pattern.substring(1));
```